# How to load custom spacynlp model on server

Tags: nlp, chatbot, spacy, named-entity-recognition, rasa

How to load custom spacyNlp ner model on ec2 server. I am facing error that "not able to load model" on server though i download it.

My custom model get load on server

Comment: Have you done spaCy installation?

Comment: Yes, I have install it.

Comment: try `pip3 install rasa[spacy]==X.X.X‍‍‍‍‍` where X.X.X is your Rasa version, and then `python3 -m spacy download en_core_web_sm`. Replace en_core_web_sm with your custom model.